# In laravel-nova how would I go about changing CREATE/UPDATE forms to have "leaving with unsaved progress" warning when changing routes?

Tags: laravel-nova

So in general in vue, implementing the unsaved progress popup is easily googlable.
The problem is specifically how to do it in laravel-nova.
Is it possible to customize the vue-router beforeRouteLeave event, to override all standard CREATE/UPDATE forms?
Preferably without changing core files, maybe with custom tools somehow?